# Mysql select that matches all array elements

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table

```
Table A
--------------------
item_id  category_id
--------------------
1        1
1        2
1        4
2        1
2        3
```

Would like to make an sql query that will select all matches in an array

***example:***

```
given category_ids are 1,4 it should return only item_id 1
given category_ids are 1 it should return  item_id 1 and 2
```

Thanks

Comment: By returning item_id 1, do you mean returning all the three (item_ids) or just the first 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For categories 1, 4:

```
SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) c
FROM TableA
WHERE category_id IN (1, 4)
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING c = 2
```

For category 1:

```
SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) c
FROM TableA
WHERE category_id IN (1)
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING c = 1
```

I think you should be able to see the pattern -- the `HAVING` clause should match the number of categories.

This assumes that `item_id, category_id` is unique in the table.

Answer (score -1):

### given category_ids are 1,4

SELECT item_id, category_id

FROM TableA

WHERE category_id IN (1, 4)

### given category_ids are 1

SELECT item_id, category_id

FROM TableA

WHERE category_id IN (1)

Comment: IN will return item_id 1 and 2 in the first example so this is wrong